# Как сделать перезарядку персонажа с помощью корутины?

Tags: c#, unity3d, coroutine

Можете помочь с написанием корутины для перезарядки?
Алгоритм такой:перед выстрелом осуществить проверку булевой переменной,которая отобразит готов ли игрок к выстрелу или нет.Эта переменная должна изменяться из инспектора.
При удачном выстреле запускается корутина, которая отсчитывает время перезарядки, установленное из инспектора, при это изменяя значение вышеописанной булевой переменной.
У меня есть одна корутина(время жизни),написанная в другом скрипте:

```
private IEnumerator StartLife()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(lifeTime);
        Destroy(gameObject);
        yield break;
    }
```

Логику второй корутины нужно написать в скрипте игрока,где я и осуществляю выстрел.Буду признателен,если поможете с написанием собственной корутины.Или исправлением нынешней.
[image: Исправленная корутина]

Comment: не делайте, пожалуйста, скриншоты кода, добавляйте его текстом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно это сделать без корутины, с помощью `Invoke()`

```
void Shoot()
{
    if (!canShoot) return;
    canShoot = false;

    // shoot logic

    Invoke(nameof(Reload), reloadTime);
}

void Reload()
{
    canShoot = true;
}
```

Если же нужна корутина, то так:

```
 void Shoot()
{
    if (!canShoot) return;
    canShoot = false;

    // shoot logic

    StartCoroutine(Reload());
}

IEnumerator Reload()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime);
    canShoot = true;
}
```

Comment: Хорошо,я попробовал ваш вариант,но у меня перестала работать логика поведения стрелы...
Вот она к слову:
```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
     GameObject prefab=Instantiate
     (arrow,arrowSpawnPoint.position,Quaternion.identity);

     prefab.GetComponent<Arrow>().SetImpulse
     (Vector2.right,spriteRenderer.flipX ?-force * shootForce: force * shootForce ,gameObject);
```

Comment: Invoke использует рефлексию, что не очень быстро.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker корутины аллоцируют на старте, а потом и при создании экземпляра WaitForSeconds в данном случае, что тоже не есть хорошо. Я лично использую UniTask, но тут уж каждый сам решает, поэтому и 2 варианта.

Comment: @Юрий bool canShoot должен быть true на старте, чтобы можно было сделать первый выстрел, потом он уже будет меняться логикой перезарядки.

Comment: @luvjungle если не хочется аллоцировать - стоит вручную проверять перезарядку в апдейте через машину состояний, например.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker с этим примером да, но я скорее про более сложные случаи, когда всё же проще использовать что-то асинхронное

Comment: Хорошо,понял,спасибо всем за комментарии)